# Changes in Heroku. How to continue having free Cloudflare SSL on free Heroku dynos?

Tags: ssl, heroku, ssl-certificate, cloudflare, heroku-ssl

Heroku email from today:

> When an app is migrated to the new infrastructure, its default
> appname.herokuapp.com, DNS records, and any haiku.herokudns.com custom
> domain records are modified to point to the IP addresses of the new
> routing infrastructure. For a period of 24-48 hours, the app is
> accessible via both the new and old routing infrastructure. When the
> migration completes, the app will no longer be accessible via the old
> routing infrastructure and all traffic must flow via the new
> infrastructure. Requests for an app sent to the old infrastructure
> will result in error code: H31 Misdirected Request.
>
> To get correct and future-proof DNS targets for custom domains
> associated with your Heroku apps, you can run heroku domains and
> compare the DNS target in the output to the CNAME target that you’ve
> configured with your DNS provider. If the DNS targets don’t match, you
> need to update your DNS configuration to point to the DNS targets
> provided by Heroku.

I’ve done the above. This then breaks the workaround to get free SSL from cloudflare to work with Heroku (because of the move away from *herokuapp.com, which allowed the workaround). So, now one has to upload a cloudflare certificate by using Heroku SSL (which one can only use on paid dynos)

Rest of the email:

> If you have any SSL Endpoints associated to your app, you can verify
> the DNS by following this step from the SSL Endpoint setup
> documentation. Please note that the SSL Endpoint add-on is deprecated
> and will be removed starting July 31, 2021. All existing and new
> Heroku applications should use Heroku SSL, which includes Automated
> Certificate Management (ACM).

Anyone with a workaround to enable the use of cloudflare SSL in a free Heroku dynos setup?

Comment: What error did you get when you set it up the way they asked?

Comment: @Ked Mardemootoo, when you get to the point of uploading the certificate to Heroku you get a message saying you can only use Heroku SSL (the only way to upload a certificate) with paid dynos. So that is where this flow breaks. You either have paid dynos or can't use free cloudflare SSL on custom domains in heroku. Sadly, a bunch of hobby apps will go down in July because of this.

Comment: @Pat would you mind me asking what steps you're taking to migrate? The reason I asked is that I received this email, too, and had setup Cloudflare <> Heroku with a free Cloudflare SSL certificate ages ago.

Comment: @Matt haven't taken the time to migrate away from Heroku + Cloudflare yet. And I have a substantial amount of side projects using that setup. Opened tickets with Cloudflare to find a workaround and saw a few messages on this in their forum. Still no solution, nor acknowledgement of the issue. It will be hobby apps doomsday end of this month. Please share should you find a workaround.

Comment: @Pat will do. I've also opened a ticket with Heroku to get more clarity on how my apps are affected, more specifically. Let's keep in touch if we learn anything.